# Macro doesn't show in list

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I want to export messages to Excel. However, when I try running the macro, I don't see it in the list.

I just copied the code below from http://www.slipstick.com/developer/vba-copy-outlook-email-excel-workbook

```vb
Option Explicit
Const xlUp As Long = -4162

Sub CopyToExcel(olItem As Outlook.MailItem)
   Dim xlApp As Object
   Dim xlWB As Object
   Dim xlSheet As Object
   Dim rCount As Long
   Dim bXStarted As Boolean
   Dim strPath As String

   Dim M1 As Object
   Dim M As Object
   Dim lgLastRow As Long 'specify the last data row

   lgLastRow = Range("A1048576").End(xlUp).Row 'Take Note: very useful!!

   enviro = CStr(Environ("username"))

   'the path of the workbook
   strPath = enviro & "C:\Desktop\Project\SR History File.xlsx"
   On Error Resume Next
   Set xlApp = GetObject(, "Excel.Application")
   If Err <> 0 Then
       Application.StatusBar = "Please wait while Excel source is opened ... "
       Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
       bXStarted = True
   End If
   On Error GoTo 0

   'Open the workbook to input the data
   Set xlWB = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(strPath)
   Set xlSheet = xlWB.Sheets("Sheet1")

   'Find the next empty line of the worksheet
    rCount = lgLastRow = Range("A1048576").End(xlUp).Row + 1

   xlSheet.Range("A" & rCount) = olItem.SentOn
   xlSheet.Range("B" & rCount) = olItem.SenderEmailAddress
   xlSheet.Range("C" & rCount) = olItem.Subject

   xlWB.Close 1
   If bXStarted Then
       xlApp.Quit
   End If
   Set M = Nothing
   Set M1 = Nothing
   Set Reg1 = Nothing
   Set xlApp = Nothing
   Set xlWB = Nothing
   Set xlSheet = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: `strPath = enviro & "C:\Desktop\Project\SR History File.xlsx"` should be `strPath = enviro & "\Desktop\Project\SR History File.xlsx"` - are you getting any errors?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I still cant see the macro when I press F5. Is this because of any setting or is it because of the code?

Comment: its the code - to see it, change `Sub CopyToExcel(olItem As Outlook.MailItem)` to `Sub CopyToExcel()` and add the following to `Dim olItem As Outlook.MailItem`

Answer (score 0):

The code cannot run without a parameter, olItem.

Open a mailitem then run this, which will be in the list.

```
Option Explicit

Sub CopyToExcel_Test
    Dim currItem as mailitem
    Set currItem = ActiveInspector.currentitem

    CopyToExcel currItem

ExitRoutine:
    Set currItem = Nothing

End Sub
```