# How to run VBA from ThisOutlookSession? The “Macros” dialog opens up

Tags: vba, debugging, outlook

I'm trying to create a macro that will run upon receipt of a new email in the inbox, check to see if the email is from a certain domain, and if it's not from that domain, add the sender to Contacts.

When I press the F5 (run) or F8 (step into), all I get is the "Macros" window popping up and a chime sound. I've tried shutting down Outlook and reopening and then running again. Same thing.

I used to work extensively with Excel and Access VBA up through 2004.

The code is in ThisOutlookSession. I'm using Outlook in Microsoft365 (the most current version).

```
Private WithEvents Items As Outlook.Items

Private Sub Application_Startup()
    Dim olApp As Outlook.Application
    Dim objNS As Outlook.NameSpace
    Set olApp = Outlook.Application
    Set objNS = olApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    ' default local Inbox
    Set Items = objNS.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).Items
End Sub

Private Sub Items_ItemAdd(ByVal item As Object)
    On Error GoTo ErrorHandler
    Dim Msg As Outlook.MailItem
    If TypeName(item) = "MailItem" Then
        Set Msg = item
        MsgBox "This is fun"
    End If
    ProgramExit:
        Exit Sub
    ErrorHandler:
        MsgBox Err.Number & " - " & Err.Description
    Resume ProgramExit
End Sub
```

Image of the "Macros" window that pops up.
[image]

[image]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34429495/macro-doesnt-show-in-list

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you need to declare functions as public to see them on the list.

You can set a breakpoint and run the `Startup` event handler by running F5. The `ItemAdd` event handler is only fired when an item is added to the folder. So, you can also set a breakpoint and wait until it fires.

Anyway, I'd recommend handling the `NewMailEx` event of the `Application` class instead. The `NewMailEx` event fires when a new message arrives in the Inbox and before client rule processing occurs. You can use the Entry ID returned in the `EntryIDCollection` array to call the `NameSpace.GetItemFromID` method and process the item. This event fires once for every received item that is processed by Microsoft Outlook. The item can be one of several different item types, for example, `MailItem`, `MeetingItem`, or `SharingItem`. The `EntryIDsCollection` string contains the Entry ID that corresponds to that item.

Finally, you may find the [Getting started with VBA in Office](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/library-reference/concepts/getting-started-with-vba-in-office) article helpful.