# Forward email to a specific address & add text to the subject line which includes a portion of the senders email address

Tags: vba, email, outlook

I am looking to create a macro that forward emails to an email address and add a line to the subject, “On behalf of @sender’s alias ” where sender's alias is their email address minus the @ and everything after

I've found a few macros (that I also cannot get to run, yet others do) that will forward the email and update the subject (example below), but I don't see how I would add the "sender alias" in this situation. I also don't know why I can't get the below macro to show up.

```
Sub ForwardEmail(Item As Outlook.MailItem)`
    With Item.Forward
        .Subject = ("On behalf of @sender’s alias ") & Item.Subject
        .Recipients.Add "backup@email.com"
        ' You need to overwrite the Body or HTMLBody to get rid of the auto signature
        .HTMLBody = Item.HTMLBody ' <-- Or use .Body for Plain Text
        '.Display ' <-- For Debug
        .Send ' <-- Put break here to Debug
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34429495/macro-doesnt-show-in-list

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [NameSpace.CurrentUser](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.namespace.currentuser) property which returns the display name of the currently logged-on user as a `Recipient` object where you could call the [Address](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.recipient.address) property which returns a string representing the email address of the `Recipient`.